# MySql login error after installing Xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

I recently installed Xampp in windows 10 and made changes to config file to overcome port error but mysql in cmd stopped working and it gives below error when i try to login.

I almost tried everything on internet.

C:\Users\Lenovo>mysql -u root -p
Enter password: ******
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: I vote tor moving this to superuser. It is a SW configuration/usage question, not one on programming.

Answer (score -1):

go to xampp / phpmyadmin and in config put you password